# Azure url encoding/decoding issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've recently moved a Rails 6 web application to Azure Web App service using Linux from an AWS Elastic beanstalk environment. I'm having an issue with a particular URL, when searching the following link:

```
www.website.com/link/asd%2Fasw
```

I get a 404 error. In my browser the link remains as `www.website.com/link/asd%2Fasw`, but in myWeb App service logs it decodes the URL to:

```
www.website.com/link/asd/asw
```

Hence why we get the 404 page error. I'm unsure of why this is happening. In our AWS environment the logs recorded the link as `www.website.com/link/asd%2Fasw` and everything was working as it should.

I have tried modifying the web.config file, but have been told that being a Linux environment this file is not supported (unsure of if this is correct).

Comment: Where you get `www.website.com/link/asd%2Fasw` ? Or you just paste it in browser ?

Comment: Web.config is only use for iis.

Comment: Thanks @JasonPan. The url is pasted in.

Comment: Do you find another way to solve it ? In linux, you can add .htaccess or nginx.conf, which depend on which web server in your linux webapp.

Comment: No other way I have found. Something to look into I guess with nginx or htaccess.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If you have a good solution, you can share it, which can help forum users who encounter the same problem.